# Determine if a TIBTransaction has pending changes

Tags: delphi, transactions, delphi-xe2, firebird

I'm working with Embarcadero Delphi XE2 and Firebird DB, using `TIBDatabase`, `TIBTransaction` and `TIBTable` components. In a form user can edit data of a DB table and commit/rollback the changes when he wants. **When he closes the form I'd like to ask him if he wants to commit/rollback pending changes.**

**But only if there are pending changes**. Otherwise I don't want to bother/confuse the user. **How can I determine it?** I tried `Active` and `InTransaction` transaction's properties, but they are always true. If it can be usefull, note that I set `AllowAutoStart` to true on the transaction. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could keep track of the pending updates yourself: turn the flag on in your table's [`AfterDelete`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.AfterDelete) and [`AfterPost`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.AfterPost) events; turn it off in [`AfterTransactionEnd`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/de/IBCustomDataSet.TIBCustomDataSet.AfterTransactionEnd):

```
// IBTable1.AfterDelete
procedure TForm1.IBTable1AfterDelete(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  FPendingUpdates := True;
end;

// IBTable1.AfterPost
procedure TForm1.IBTable1AfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  FPendingUpdates := True;
end;

// IBTable1.AfterTransactionEnd
procedure TForm1.IBTable1AfterTransactionEnd(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FPendingUpdates := False;
end;

// Form1.OnCloseQuery
procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
var
  DlgResult: TModalResult;
begin
  CanClose := False;

  if FPendingUpdates then
    DlgResult := MessageDlg('Commit pending updates before closing?', mtConfirmation,
      [mbYes, mbNo, mbCancel], 0, mbCancel)
  else
    DlgResult := mrNo;

  case DlgResult of
    mrYes:
      IBTransaction1.Commit;
    mrNo:
      IBTransaction1.Rollback;
    mrCancel:
      Exit;
  end;

  CanClose := True;
end;
```

Comment: there is one more event to hook - AfterInsert ;-)

Comment: @Arioch'The No, `AfterInsert` has nothing to do with the server transaction - it's fired when a record is inserted in the dataset's local buffer. (You have to `Post` after `Insert`/`Append` to send the insert to the server.)

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.AppendRecord - would it call AfterInsert or AfterPost ?

Comment: @Arioch'The My short experience shows `AfterPost` is triggered after both insert and update so no need to write in `AfterInsert`. Thanks to everybody!

Comment: EMBA documentation team suggests OnNewRecord and AfterInsert on AppendRecord. Would have to re-check...

Comment: from what i can see in VCL sources of procedure TDataSet.AddRecord (and that is implementing call for both InsertRecord and AppendRecord, and it seems they all are not-virtual calls) there would be the whole cycle of state changing and a lot of events
 
  DoBeforeInsert;
  DoBeforeScroll;
  DoOnNewRecord;
  DoAfterInsert;
  DoBeforePost;
  DoAfterPost;

Answer (score 2):

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/IBDatabase.TIBTransaction.SQLObjects

Enumerate all tables for that transaction and ask those tables if they have pending changes. If none has - then silently commit and exit. If some has - prompt user.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I know if a table has pending changes? All changed could have been `Post`ed, but not yet committed with the transaction... does `TIBTable` know that?

Comment: Natural way for FB/IB work is dual-transaction: one read-only read-commited transaction is used only for reading w/o closing it during program execution. While many short r/w transactions are used to save certain changes. That way you'd had only to annalyze 2nd transaction state... Pity IBX seems to not support it.

Comment: So you'd probably have to follow TOndrej pattern, after transaction started enumerate datasets and mark them as "no changes" (like for example const db_no_changes = 100; // dataset.Tag := db_no_changes ) and set all those datasets' event handlers to hook AfterDelete/AfterInsert/AfterPost to change the mark. Then those handlers would track if certain dataset had changed something.

Comment: But generally i think you app design is wrong. If you changed something - you should commit it with short transaction. Otherwise imaging network error or server crash - all your uncommited changes would be lost, even if user made them in grid hour ago. I cannot hardly imagine situation when you have to start editing transaction and u don't know when to close it.